# Kotlin - KFunction3 unresolved reference

Tags: kotlin

```
val fooCtor = ::Foo
```

The inferred type of `fooCtor` is `KFunction3<Int, Int, Int, Foo>`

When I try to explicitly define something as `KFunction3<...>`, for example

```
val fooCtor: KFunction3<Int, Int, Int, Foo> = ::Foo
```

The IDE/compiler tells me that `KFunction3` is an unresolved reference.

Why is this? - I tried adding kotlin-reflect to my gradle.build file but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce your problem with IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.6 with:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    fun foo(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = x % 2 != 0
    val f = ::foo
    val f1: KFunction3<Int, Int, Int, Boolean> = ::foo
}
```

This compiles without any problem.

How come that the return type is `Foo` in KFunction3? Does your `Foo` function return itself?

**Update 1:**

I have tested the same with a constructor with no errors:

```
class Foo (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) {}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val ft1 = ::Foo
    val ft2: KFunction3<Int, Int, Int, Foo> = ::Foo
}
```

Using Kotlin 1.2.31 and no extra libraries.

Comment: Yes, `::Foo` is a constructor, so it returns an instance of `Foo`

Comment: @series0ne I have tested also with a constructor. See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Through `KFunction3` is not part of the standard lib you have to manually import it.

```
import kotlin.reflect.KFunction3
```

This solved your problem for me.

Comment: Not sure why idea is not suggesting the import. This is best answer!